# Get controller and action names with pjax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, history, pushstate, pjax

In my application I use this technique:

```
<body id="action" class="controller">
```

Is there a way to [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) send it along with the `#container`?

Comment: Not sure I understand - send what along? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rails:

I don't know what you're using to generate the server side response. I am using [rack-pjax](https://github.com/eval/rack-pjax/), and was able to modify the library to set the class and id on the body with the following:

```
--- pjax.orig.rb    2012-05-04 22:46:22.000000000 -0700
+++ pjax.rb 2012-05-04 22:46:57.000000000 -0700
@@ -13,6 +13,10 @@
       headers = HeaderHash.new(headers)

       if pjax?(env)
+        request_parameters = env['action_dispatch.request.parameters']
+        controller_name    = request_parameters[:controller]
+        action_name        = request_parameters[:action]
+
         new_body = ""
         body.each do |b|
           parsed_body = Hpricot.XML(b)
@@ -22,6 +26,13 @@

             new_body << title.to_s if title
             new_body << container.inner_html
+            new_body << <<-EOS
+              <script type="text/javascript">
+                $('body').removeClass();
+                $('body').addClass('#{controller_name}');
+                $('body').attr('id', '#{action_name}');
+              </script>
+            EOS
           else
             new_body << b
           end
```